# Why is my c# test app blocking on one async function, but not another?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a piece of equipment that I can interact with via the accompanying API library provided by the equipment vendor. Most of the activity involves connecting to it, opening/closing its door, and a few other tasks. I've wrapped most of the vendor's synchronous API function calls in Task.Run() to use in a winforms test app to avoid blocking the UI. This has mostly worked, except for the initial Connect call that will block unless I use ConfigureAwait(false) when creating the equipment proxy object. I am struggling to understand *why* this function, and so far only this function, is causing the application UI to hang until it completes, while others (like the one to close the door) do not.

The SomeProxy object is a part of the vendor's API that inherits from RealProxy, but I have no access to its inner workings.

Excerpts of control functions:

```
        private async void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Client.ConnectAsync(address);
        }

        private async void buttonCloseDoor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Client.CloseDoorAsync();
        }
```

Async functions:

```
        public async Task ConnectAsync(string address)
        {
                //some stuff happens here

                // this blocks 
                //PieceOfEquipment = await Task.Run(() => VendorAPI.SomeProxy.Create(address)); 

                // this does not block
                PieceOfEquipment = await Task.Run(() => VendorAPI.SomeProxy.Create(address)).ConfigureAwait(false); 

                // some more stuff happens after

        }

        public async Task CloseDoorAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => PieceOfEquipment.CloseDoor()); // this does not block
        }
```

I appreciate it may be hard to say why given the black-boxed API functionality, but I am hoping to deepen my understanding here.

Comment: Your problem is `private async void buttonConnect_Click` this tends to have some weird behaviour when things don't go well. You should really be using `private async Task buttonConnect_Click` [Article on Pluralsight about returning void from async methods](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/returning-void-from-c-async-method)

Comment: In CloseDoorAsync(), create a task, start it and return it. Do not await.

Comment: Does that api library specifically for winforms, or is general purpose?

Comment: I would check the documentation on `ConfigureAwait` if you haven't already. It seems that the synchronization context is very relevant here.

Comment: So keep using the `ConfigureAwait(false)` and check the documentation on the proxy creation. `ConfigureAwait(false)` essentially used to avoid forcing the callback to be invoked on the original context so if the proxy creation process doesn't return anything then its safe to use it that way.

Comment: I can't think of any reason that any of these lines would cause a deadlock. Have you tried to run the program without the debugger attached? (Ctrl+F5)

Comment: @ phuzi - I'd agree in general, but given that it's a top-level / control event handler I don't see what difference that would make.

@ Tarik - I can't quite do that, as I may need to add in more code before/after that will depend on awaiting that function return.

@ Evk - general purpose, it comes as a handful of DLLs.

@ JamesFaix @HMZ - certainly seems to be something hinging on the synchronization context, and I wonder if it's something weird to do with the way .NET remoting works.

@ theodor no change in behaviour.

Comment: @mag It doesn't, `async void` methods' purpose is to make asynchronous event handlers possible. The most notable thing is that they handle exceptions differentely.

Comment: @HMZ I think we're talking about the same thing, and I'm not planning on throwing any exceptions from those control event handlers. Either way, I don't think they're impacting the odd async behaviour I'm observing.